# Drupal, or Joomla Form Builder 

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, joomla1.5

I am evaluating Drupal and Joomla, and one of the requirements I have is how well supported it is when comes to Form Building, storing the information in the database, and the showing of those information upon query.

I don't know which one is better in this regard, Drupal or Joomla? Is there any third party extension I have to install for this purpose?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the sorts of forms you want to build & how you want to review the results?

Comment: The kinds of forms I want to build: a listing form webpage for properties. So the user can submit a picture of their house, location and description on a page. When it gets submitted, it will be posted on the web and other people can view them

Answer (score 3):

Drupal has the [Content Construction Kit](http://drupal.org/project/cck) module, commonly known in the community as CCK.  Combining the functionality of CCK with the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module is a common way of getting the functionality you're after.

The terminology involved with this in the Drupal world might take some getting used to but there is plenty of documentation around.  A quick [Google search on the terms: drupal cck views](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=drupal+cck+views) reveals a ton of useful results.

Answer (score 1):

CCK allows you to define arbitrary fields in a Drupal node. Each of those fields is configured with a particular type and input widget (select box, text field, checkboxes, etc),  as well as weight (top-to-bottom presentation ordering). There's also stuff like default values, help text, text and location of labels - pretty much everything you'd need.

And if that is not enuf, Drupal also includes a wide array of hook functions including form_alter() which, along with some well-designed page/node templates and CSS styling, pretty much gives you capability to change virtually anything about the appearance of a node's presentation. All the other things you list - storing and retrieving form values is pretty much handled for free for you, which one would expect from any CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has a Forms API through which you can build forms, alter existing forms and even create new widgets. It's by design more powerful than Joomla's.

- [Forms API Quickstart Guide](http://api.drupal.org/api/file/developer/topics/forms_api_reference.html/6)
- [Forms API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/file/developer/topics/forms_api.html/6)

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla take a look at http://www.joomla-forms.com :-)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has a couple of CCK-like extensions, a few of them released within the last two months: [k2](http://k2.joomlaworks.gr/) and [zoo](http://zoo.yootheme.com/). [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/) is also worth a mention.

You could probably use any of them to do what you need.

If you're looking to set up a real-estate or classifieds site, there are proper extensions for all that in the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As a novice developer, you can estimate both by looking at [joomla-builder.com](http://joomla-builder.com) and [lhttp://drupal-builder.net](http://drupal-builder.net). Both are online site builders, and contain the list of top popular modules.

In Joomla, you can build custom forms with [ChronoForms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/1508/details)ChronoForms. To build page for real estate, you can use [HotProperty](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate/232/details) component. Also check out [EZRealty](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate/614/details) - also quite popular.

In Drupal, you can use a few more general and abstract modules together to achive what you need. In general these modules are CCK and Views.

Also, some people generate very [CodeCharge Studio](http://yessoftware.com) customized database-driven pages in CodeCharge Studio, and then integrate them into Joomla or Drupal as separate pages or as inline pages.